# Type of Mysql Join to remove from query list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 three tables: `a`, `aLocale`, `aCompany`.

I need to get all the rows where `a.id = aLocale.parentID` if `aCompany.parentID` does not exist.

I know that `aLocale` would be an `innerJoin` but what about `aCompany`?

I could also be looking at the problem wrong. The only reason I am using aCompany is if matching row doesn't exist. Currently, I am running a query for `a` and getting the results as an array. I then iterate through the array and unset the items that match a separate query of `aCompany`. I feel there would be a better way of doing it with 1 query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, this will return even non matching values

```
SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN aLocale ON a.id = alocale.parentID 
LEFT JOIN aCompany ON aCompany.parentID = alocale.parentID 
WHERE aCompany.parentID IS NULL
```

Edited:
You can also get parentID not null using coalesce() instead of * in your select

```
SELECT COALESCE(aCompany.parentID, aLocale.parentID) AS parentID FROM ....
```

Using coalesce() you'll find the first not null value among arguments list

Comment: I used the leftJoin option as it better suited my situation. Thanks!

Comment: I meant you can combine them, using left join doesn't exclude second.
ie:

`SELECT COALESCE(aCompany.parentID, aLocale.parentID) AS parentID FROM a INNER JOIN aLocale ON a.id = alocale.parentID 
LEFT JOIN aCompany ON aCompany.parentID = alocale.parentID 
WHERE aCompany.parentID IS NULL`

**combined** will set on parentID the value aCompany.parentID only if exists, so that you avoid checking the existence of the value (or the lack of it) when you fetch the row